# Revision contains null values of other fields if change the @oneToMany - entity by adding a new entity

Tags: hibernate-envers

When a new address is added for a person, a new revision should be created. A revision is created, but the remaining fields of the entity in the revision are marked null.

Different and correct:
When I change a name for a person, a revision is created where all fields are entered.

Person Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Audited
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

Person Audit Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_aud")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class PersonAud implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AuditIdentity auditIdentity;

    @Column(name = "revtype")
    private Short revtype;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("auditIdentity.id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    @OneToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

Address Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Audited
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;


    @Column(name = "house_number")
    private String houseNumber;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state_province")
    private String stateProvince;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("addresses")
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("addresses")
    @NotAudited
    private PersonAud personAud;
```

If I add a new address that belongs to person XY, then my table looks like this:

PERSON_AUD:
ID: 1
REV: 1001
REVTYPE: 1
FIRST_NAME: NULL
LAST_NAME: NULL

For example, if I change the first name, the fields for the first_name and last_name are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (not perfect):

I changed the line:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
        private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

Now the process works like:

1. Add a new person with empty Address array
2. Add a new Address which refers to the person id
3. Action like a PUT on this Person assigning the address-object.

= PERSON_AUD table will contain the revision and the fields.

**PROBLEM:**
 it is not perfect because you have to assign the address manually to the person.

Is there any other possible solution?